# NestJs Testing create a single instance of app across all tests

Tags: nestjs

I am running into the issue `Error querying the database: db error: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already` and I am convinced it is because a new instance of the app is being instantiated for every test suite. I have attempted to break the app creation out into a helper file, and that file looks as follows

```
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppModule } from '../../src/app.module';
import { PrismaService } from '../../src/prisma.service';

declare global {
  var app: INestApplication | undefined;
}

export const getApp = async () => {
  if (global.app) {
    return global.app;
  }

  const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
    providers: [PrismaService],
  }).compile();

  const app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
  await app.init();
  global.app = app;
  return app;
};
```

This however does not work, when I add console logs, I can see that app is being instantiated for every test suite.

This is how my typical before hook looks

```
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it by using Jest's [globalSetup](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalsetup-string) and [globalTeardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalteardown-string) options. I create one instance of the app and seed the DB before running the tests, and destroy it and run the teardown when they've finished. I use a global variable to reference the app instance.

In my `jest-e2e.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "globalSetup": "<rootDir>/test/test-setup.ts",
    "globalTeardown": "<rootDir>/test/test-teardown.ts"
}
```

`test-setup.ts`:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';
import { WriteDataSource } from './../src/database/database.module';

module.exports = async () => {

    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({

        imports: [ AppModule ]

    })
    .compile();

    global.app = moduleRef.createNestApplication<NestFastifyApplication>(

        new FastifyAdapter()
        
    );
    
    await global.app.init();
    await global.app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().ready();

    const seedQuery = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/scripts/database-seed.sql', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
    await WriteDataSource.manager.query(seedQuery);

};
```

`test-teardown.ts`:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

import { WriteDataSource } from '../src/database/database.module';

module.exports = async () => {

    const teardownQuery = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/scripts/database-teardown.sql', { encoding: 'utf-8' }).replace(/\n/g, '');
    await WriteDataSource.query(teardownQuery);

    await WriteDataSource.destroy();

    await global.app.close();

};
```

Comment: I am currently trying this. While setup and teardown run fine, I'm getting an undefined error when trying to access global.app from within the tests itself. I assume the global vars can't be accessed from within the tests?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by exporting the server instance and everything else i needed:

```
let server: Server
let app: INestApplication
let testService: TestService

export const initServer = async () => {
  const module = Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule, TestModule]
  })
 
  const testModule = await module.compile()

  app = testModule.createNestApplication()
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true
    })
  )

  server = app.getHttpServer()
  testService = app.get(TestService)

  await app.init() 
}

export { app, server, testService }
```

Here i exported the function to clear all my databases to use where needed:

```
export const clearAllDatabases = async () => {
  models.map(async (model: any) => {
    await model.destroy({
      where: {},
      truncate: true,
      cascade: true
    })
  })
}
```

```
import { app, initServer } from '@tests/resources/config/test-server'
import { clearAllDatabases } from '@tests/resources/config/clear-databases'

export const setupTestData = async () => {
  await initServer()
  await clearAllDatabases()
  await userRegister()  
  await app.close()
}
```